# IE 7, CSS Hover Items over a JS Slider

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, hover

The Issue I am having is that I have a JS Slider in the center area. But also a CSS Drop Down menu right above it. Every browser the hover effect works except the dreaded IE 7 & 6 [not worried about 6]. I am not sure how to display the UL menus over the JS Slider as the Z-Index function has not really done anything as I set the hover over containers at 999 and the actual images in the slider are only 5. Any ideas.

Site where issue is happening: http://www.metroclick.com/

All answers are definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the whole slider fiv z-index to 1, and the ul to z-index 999, that should do the work...

Comment: Just tried to do that, I set the #gallery-holder and .slideshow to Z-Index 1 and the Menu Ul to 999 still no go. No exactly sure whats blocking it anymore.

Comment: one of them is positioned absolute?

Comment: All of the images under .slideshow's - ul are position:absolute remove it?

Comment: Tried it definitely destroyed the slider.

Comment: the z-index is set on the original items or on the hover state ones?

Comment: Fixed, I think I applied the z-index to the wrong ul li style as I have so many for just the nav. Thank you for sticking with me and helping me out!